# Converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3 errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Im working my way through [this](http://www.andypierz.com/blog/2014/11/9/basic-drag-and-drop-uitableviews-using-swift-and-core-data) tutorial on using a gesture on a tableview cell with CoreData.

I got most of it converted by there are 2 places where I have ran into an issue.

1.

**Swift2:**

```
snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
```

**Swift 3:**

```
snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransform.scaledBy(1.05, 1.05)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Use of instance member 'scaledBy' on type 'CGAffineTransform'; did you mean to use a value of type 'CGAffineTransform' instead?
```

---

Here is the 2nd issue.

**Swift 2:**

```
 let bool:Bool = indexPath!.isEqual(beginningIndexPath) as Bool
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let bool:Bool = indexPath!.isEqual(beginningIndexPath) as Bool
```

error:

```
Value of type 'IndexPath' has no member 'isEqual'
```

I tried to use the == as a replacement, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I get an error saying that UIView has no member 'scaledBy'

Comment: You can also say: `snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(1.05, 1.05)`

Comment: 2nd issue: `==` is supposed to work if `beginningIndexPath` is also `IndexPath` (without `NS`). And don't bridge cast a `Bool` to a `Bool` – which is the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First issue, use an initializer:

```
CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
```

Second issue, use the `elementsEqual`:

```
let bool = indexPath!.elementsEqual(beginningIndexPath)
```

Comment: .init is useless and should be omitted to be clearer

Comment: I bow to you - the init should be omitted

Comment: `let bool = indexPath!.elementsEqual(beginningIndexPath)`
 produces this error `: Argument type 'NSIndexPath!' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'`

Comment: Are you comparing an NSIndexPath with an IndexPath? NSIndexPath inherits from NSObject so they have the `isEqual` method. IndexPath is a struct, so it does not have this method. If beginningIndexPath is an NSIndexPath, you should consider casting it, or use `beginningIndexPath.isEqual(indexPath!)`

Answer (score 0):

**First issue:**

It should be:

```
snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
```

You should use [init(scale​X:​y:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455016-init) CGAffineTransform initializer.

Swift 3 has many improvements on working with C APIs, you might want to check [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md).

---

**Second issue:**

It should be:

```
let bool = indexPath == beginningIndexPath!
```

Note that [IndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath) *Struct* is conforms to [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable) Protocol, `==` operator should works fine.

If you are using `isEqual` then I assume that `indexPath` was an instance of [NSIndexPath](http://NSIndex%E2%80%8BPath); I recommend to check the `NSIndexPath` *class* Documentation:

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Index​Path
>   structure, which bridges to the NSIndex​Path class. The Index​Path
>   value type offers the same functionality as the NSIndex​Path reference
>   type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that
>   interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift
>   bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their
>   corresponding Foundation classes.

You can find what's the exact reason behind that by check [Mutability and Foundation Value Types Proposal.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md)